# How to install Mono 2.6 on Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-9.10, repository, mono-framework

I need urgently to install Mono 2.6 on Ubuntu 9.10 but in Synaptic the version 2.6 doesn't appear :-(

Is there an other repository I can use to install it ?

Comment: What makes your require 2.6?  Is there a specific feature you need that keeps you from using 2.4?

Comment: I need Linq to sql feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the latest version in the official repos is 2.4.  So you've got a couple of options.  If you're just using it temporarily you can download a virtual machine or live CD which has the latest build on it from the [Mono download page](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html).  However, if a VM or live CD will not do, you may have to [compile Mono](http://mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono) from source.

Comment: The last time I compile the source of Mono 2.6, Monodevellop didn't start :-( so I prefer to use a repository with the package.

Comment: I will try the vmware image of OpenSuse provided by www.mono-project.com

Answer (score 0):

You can [install](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.6.3#Installing_Mono_2.6.1) mono from [source](http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/sources-stable/).

Comment: The last time I compile the source of Mono 2.6, Monodevellop didn't start :-( so I would prefer to use a repository with a package.

Comment: you shouldn't overwrite the packaged mono... install it in parralel.

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments

Comment: I don't understand the /opt/gnome I haven't it. But is it just to create a new folder /opt/mono and install the source within ?

Comment: It would be probably easier for you to uninstall current mono environment in ubuntu (if you don't use some program which needs it) and then install 2.6 from source.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer... You can't

Long answer... you can compile it from source but this requires you to be a quite advanced user. The mono project is produced by Novell, Novell has a linux distro called opensuse which competes with Ubuntu. Novell therefore has no incentive to package mono for ubuntu.

I have asked this same question on the mono mailing list the answer was that it is up to the ubuntu devs to package mono for ubuntu.  Seeing as ubuntu only packages stuff for its 6 monthly releases this means that they will not provide packaging for mono releases which happen after the feature freeze.

You will probably notice that the mono project provides packaging for all other major operation systems including: windows and mac osx. But not for ubuntu even though it has the largest mono user base.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed mono 2.6 from source using the script/instructions from http://patrick.qmtech.net/blog/?p=14

It's not quite as easy as the default install, but pretty well automated for a source install. The only additional step I needed to get my build server working was updating the path and pkg-config path so that 2.6 is found before 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

The mono-cli team hasn't packaged it yet. So there are no packages to install. Further bad news is it's not coming in 10.04 (Lucid) either. So you will have to install from source, or package it yourself. Do not attempt the later... so install a parallel version of mono and you will not break your distro supplied mono. You can pick and choose which mono to use to run/build your apps. Get the script from [my blog](http://patrick.qmtech.net/blog/?p=14)...

```
wget http://patrick.qmtech.net/downloads/mono_parallel.sh
chmod +x mono_parallel.sh
./mono_parallel.sh
```

Then...

```
mono-2.6 banshee-1
mono-2.6 mono -V
mono-2.6 your-app
```

Newer version of MonoDevelop will find your parallel version of mono and allow you to compile against either. Cool huh?